# Does Licensing have to be mentioned for MIT/BSD-3 Plugins/Libraries for my Commercial Website?

Tags: software, licensing

If I create a commercial website that uses MIT/BSD-3 libraries and plugins, do I have to specifically mention the licences of each plugin/library? If so where do I have to add the same? Are the comments that are present in the library js/css which credits the author enough? E.g.

```
/*! 
 * Bootstrap v4.1.3 (https://getbootstrap.com/) 
 * Copyright 2011-2018 The Bootstrap Authors 
 * Copyright 2011-2018 Twitter, Inc. 
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE) 
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIT license says

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included *in
>   all copies or substantial portions* of the Software.

So the comments inside the library itself should be enough; just make sure they don't get stripped away by a minifier or equivalent.

---

As for BSD-3, assuming you're talking about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#3-clause_license_(%22BSD_License_2.0%22,_%22Revised_BSD_License%22,_%22New_BSD_License%22,_or_%22Modified_BSD_License%22)), you should include the full text - including the names of the authors, etc - in some page of the website.